# $a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2 = 12$ - prove that $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1) \leq 27$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, means

I've got stuck on this problem :

> Let $a, b, c \geq 0$ such that $a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2 = 12$. Prove that $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1) \leq 27$.

I've thought that mean inequality ($HM \leq GM \leq AM \leq PM$ - referring to harmonic, geometric, arithmetic and square mean) may help. I've also considered $CBS$ (Cauchy - Buniakowski - Scwarz) inequality and Cebîşev inequality, but I didn't get it right.

I would be thankful for some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{a ^ 2 + b ^ 2}{2} + \frac{c ^ 2 + b ^ 2}{2} + \frac{a ^ 2 + c ^ 2}{2} = 12$$
$$\therefore 12 \ge ab + bc + ca$$
Also,
$$\frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{3} \ge (abc)^{\frac23}$$
$$\therefore 4^{\frac32} \ge abc$$
$$\therefore 8 \ge abc$$
And finally, [RMS > A.M.](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality) gives
$$(\frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{3})^\frac12 \ge \frac{a + b  + c}{3}$$
$$\therefore 6 \ge a+b+c$$
$$\therefore 12 + 8 + 6 + 1 \ge abc + ab + bc + ca + a + b + c + 1$$
$$\therefore 27 \ge (a+1)(b+1)(c+1)$$

Answer (score 2):

You may use the GM-AM-QM inequality, i.e. to combine:
$$ (a+1)(b+1)(c+1) \leq \left(\frac{a+b+c+3}{3}\right)^3 \tag{1}$$
with:
$$ \frac{a+b+c}{3}\leq \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: The second inequality also follows by Cauchy-Schwarz: $(a+b+c)\le \sqrt{(1+1+1)\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)}$.

Comment: @user236182: yes, I agree, the AM-QM inequality is equivalent to CS inequality.

Answer (score 1):

$24=a^2+b^2+c^2 + 12 \geq 4a+4b+4c$
$a^2+b^2+c^2+2a+2b+2c+3 \leq12+12+3=27$
$(a+1)^2+(b+1)^2+(c+1)^2 \leq27$
$3\ ^3\sqrt{(a+1)^2(b+1)^2(c+1)^2} \leq (a+1)^2+(b+1)^2+(c+1)^2 \leq27$
$ ^3\sqrt{(a+1)^2(b+1)^2(c+1)^2} \leq 9$
$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1) \leq 27$